# Meta Tables appear to incorrect in Spring Batch Docs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I tried the Spring Batch *Getting Started Guide* presented [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) (code [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/tree/main/complete)).

The only change I made was to point my process to a local MySQL instance (instead of an embedded hsqldb db) to make the exercise a little more practical. To enable that, I first created the meta tables described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#metaDataSchema). I also followed the upgrade guide [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#column-change-in-batch_job_execution_params).

But running this simple job returned `Unknown column 'CREATE_TIME' in 'field list'`:

```
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) 
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) 
...
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [
 SELECT STEP_EXECUTION_ID, STEP_NAME, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, 
  READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, 
  WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED, 
  VERSION, CREATE_TIME 
 from  BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION 
 where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? order by STEP_EXECUTION_ID
]
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Unknown column 'CREATE_TIME' in 'field list'
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
```

This indicates there should be a CREATE_TIME column on table `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION`. But the meta table DDLs in the docs only show CREATE_TIME on `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION`.

So I added that column. Then I got an error indicating START_TIME on `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` cannot be null. So I made that change, too. Now the process seems to work.

Did I set something up incorrectly that resulted in these initial errors? I'm using the same framework version used in the *Getting Started* Guide. Or maybe the Spring Batch meta tables are incorrectly defined [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#metaDataBatchStepExecution)?

Comment: There are DDL scripts which create the tables for you, not sure if the image in the documentation is totally up to date and I assume that you used that image to create the tables (instead of the provided DDL scripts). The provided DDL is part of the jars and can be found here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql (on github).

Comment: Thanks for quick response! The DDLs you link to contain the changes I needed to make to BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION. The docs should really be updated to help people out. The DDLs in those docs are not just images, but text with "Copy to clipboard" buttons. I didn't find an obvious link to the DDLs on github in the docs. The [upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#column-change-in-batch_job_execution_params) doesn't mention the required BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION changes either.

Comment: Because those are in an earlier version (4.3 I believe and not 5.x), so indeed they are not part of the 5.x migration as that should already have been done.

Comment: That makes sense. The reference docs are incorrect, though. I assume others have struggled with this.

Comment: Well I doubt, as if you read the section below the image that mentions the earlier said DDL scripts for different databases. And in my experience (and using myself as a reference) people tend to be lazy and prefer pre-made scripts over copy/pasting :).

Comment: It seems odd that the docs go into much detail, but leave the details of those 2 columns incorrect, which perhaps no one but I just happened to run into. Nonetheless, it looks like the docs are not open source for updating, correct?

Comment: They are part of the repository so you can update what you like.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for raising this. The documentation was not up-to-date for v5. This was fixed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/4356

The diagram will also be updated, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4358.